# Why SourceTree always pop up the ssh window when it started

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have setted the SSH key, but when the SourceTree starts, the SSH window pops up with the SourceTree.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sourcetree says it popups the window to load your ssh key, what do you expect?

Comment: @Ferrybig I don't want to see the ssh window when it started every time.

Comment: You could try using the plink option, this program doesn't quit when you quit sourcetree, but when using this, you need to convert your ssh key to the putty format using puttygen (if sourcetree doesn't do this for you)